# jQuery not adding innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, scope

I'm having issues with adding my storedItems object key to the "current-items" div. When I  console.log(storedItems.itemName) it prints out the item name fine. Also if i move $(".current-items").html(storedItems.itemName) outside of the .click function I can seem to add innerHTML but it messes up my storedItems variable. Any suggestions?

```js
  $(".btn-add-basket").click(function() {


    const parent_id = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
    const itemName = parent_id[0].querySelector("h4");
    const itemPrice = parent_id[0].querySelector("span");
    const itemImage = parent_id[0].querySelector("img").src;

    var fullItem = {
      itemName: itemName.innerText,
      itemPrice: itemPrice.innerText,
      itemImage: itemImage
    };

    console.log(fullItem);
    localStorage.setItem("my-items", JSON.stringify(fullItem));
    var storedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("my-items"));
    console.log(storedItems.itemName);

    $(".current-items").html(storedItems.itemName);
  });
});
```

Comment: try `$(".basket-count").html(function(i, basketCount) { return basketCount })`

Comment: @Ashok might like to review that, did you mean to put `(i, basketCount)` ?

Comment: I'm confused lol. Basket count works fine. Sorry may not make sense from my code. I basically have a route to /basket which contains a div called current-items. I'm trying to show a list of the current items that the user has added

Comment: Well this is when I learn something new lol. So I need AJAX to pass my storedItem data to this route?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] - emphasis on *minimal* and *complete* - is the carousel relevant?  The modal?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I'm using node.js. I have a route set up called /basket which renders basket.ejs file.

Comment: Works fine as provided https://jsfiddle.net/zchfpom2/  - I'm assuming you're still updating, so will check back later

Comment: @Ashok clearly not - because your `basketCount` in `(i, basketCount)` overwrites the outer variable, so your code is just `$(".cls").html($(".cls").html())` which does nothing other than remove any events: see https://jsfiddle.net/9rq6x804/

Comment: Try now https://jsfiddle.net/ach9grq4/2/  clear cache

Comment: Just as a side note, you might want to add the [javascript] tag. jQuery is just a library, and can't exist without Javascript.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yeah it seems to work fine when I append it to a test div on my /store route however when I append to the ("current-items") div it does not display. I'm also noticing that my data is not saving when I refresh the page yet it is saved in localStorage. I think this may be the route of my issue